# Was Poe's The Pit and the Pendulum at all inspired by A Predicament?

Tags: short-stories, edgar-allan-poe, intertextuality

Poe's satirical short story [*A Predicament*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Predicament) tells the story of a woman who is slowly decapitated by the minute hand of a large cathedral clock. In all its ridiculousness, it was supposed to be a horror parody, a bit unlike much of the rest of Poe's writings. It was published in 1838; four years later, Poe published [*The Pit and the Pendulum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_and_the_Pendulum), a serious and more elaborate short story where the protagonist narrowly escapes death at the hand of a swinging pendulum that comes closer and closer.

Given some of the similarities, I was wondering if Poe wrote *The Pit and the Pendulum* to further emphasize the absurdity of *A Predicament* and some serious works of the genre, or if he decided to write a serious story following a similar plot.

Did Poe ever comment on the similarities of the two stories? It's quite possible that he didn't, in which case I'd be absolutely fine with interpretations from the texts. Is there evidence from the stories, or discussion from literary criticism, that suggests that he intended the two to be alike?

Comment: "*a bit unlike much of the rest of Poe's writings*" - I disagree. He might be best known for his genuine horror, but he also wrote a LOT of parody and slapstick humour as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might find [the second Sample Topic here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JxH5hmsJehcC&pg=PT138&lpg=PT138&dq=poe+predicament+pit+and+the+pendulum&source=bl&ots=owhonyZ8hz&sig=3hKFFJNUsQRHp1061cUat-BIJoU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY8aWjyvLRAhUHChoKHZlcAJkQ6AEIQzAH#v=onepage&q=poe%20predicament%20pit%20and%20the%20pendulum&f=false) amusing :-)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_and_the_Pendulum#Inspiration

Comment: "Poe published The Pit and the Pendulum, a serious and more elaborate short story where the protagonist *narrowly escapes death* at the hand of a swinging pendulum that comes closer and closer." - How did he escape death? He fell inside the pit.